# Getting nothing when doing whereBetween in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a sort function where if it's selected it will display the necessary amount of orders. For example if the user selects to display orders from the last 3 months then that needs to be displayed.

The problem I'm having is that nothing is being shown when I `dd($three_months)`

```
public function trackOrders()
{
    $menus_child = Menu::where('menu_id', 0)->with('menusP')->get();
    $contacts = Contact::all();

    $orders = Auth::user()->orders->sortByDesc('order_date');
    $orders->transform(function($order, $key){
                $order->cart = unserialize($order->cart);
                return $order;
            });

    $from = Carbon::now('+2:00');

    $to = $from->copy()->subMonth(3);

    $three_months = Order::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();

    dd($three_months);

    return view('public.users.track-orders', compact('menus_child', 'contacts', 'orders', 'order_item'));
}
```

but when I do `dd($three_months)` nothing shows up. I only get

> Collection {#320 ▼
>           #items: []
>       }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Order matters when using SQL's `BETWEEN`. Your `$from` value is greater than your `$to` value. So try swapping them around:

```
$to = Carbon::now('+2:00');

$from = $from->copy()->subMonth(3);

$three_months = Order::whereBetween('created_at', [$from, $to])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because you are not Formatting DateTime

```
   $from = Carbon::now('+2:00')->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
   $to = $from->copy()->subMonth(3)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Try This code.

Edit: You cant Use `copy()` method on string. so you can do.

```
  $to = Carbon::now('+2:00')->subMonth(3)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```